# Unnecessary huge empty space at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css, templates

This is my project: http://linguall.com/

We bought a template and edited it. I deleted some of the page that is not needed for us. However, as you scroll the bottom of the page you can spot the the huge blank space.

I could not found any reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using relative positioning on some of your elements. The problem with this is that the element still takes up space where it originally was and you will struggle to get rid of that.

I'd investigate replacing your usage of relative positioning for large blocks of content that you don't want to take up space on your page - try absolute positioning or using a grid layout.

Comment: @ege-aydın **class="browser_width colelem"** element with this class is creating issue due to *Relative position* 
Try to handle this element without relative position. to resolve the issue!